# Adding gap between specific bars in a stacked bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I have two groups of stacked bars in a chart and I would like to group them visually

So how could I add extra vertical gap between specific bars in a stacked bar chart or separate the groups in some other way?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/KrTbz/41/

I would like to add extra vertical space between bars 4 and A

```
 new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Grouping test',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', 'A', 'B', 'C', ]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'percent'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Alpha',
            data: [31, 27, 23, 22, 22, 20, 21]
        }, {
            name: 'Omega',
            data: [5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, ]
        }, {
            name: 'Gamma',
            data: [60, 62, 67, 69, 68, 70, 71]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in simple way, but only what comes to my mind is quite dirty solution but maybe will be enough. So you can set null values in series and in categories.

http://jsfiddle.net/KrTbz/42/

```
xAxis: {
        categories: [ '1','2','3','4','','A', 'B', 'C', ]     
    },

series: [
{
    name: 'Alpha',
    data: [31,27,23,22,null,22,20,21]

}, {
    name: 'Omega',
    data: [5,6,7,5,null,6,6,5,]

} ,{
    name: 'Gamma',
    data: [60,62,67,69,null,68,70,71] 
}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Not perfect, but works for me in this case. I had thought this solution earlier but were not able to figure out that I should set **null** values in series to get and empty bar.